# How to use HttpWebRequest.Credentials Property for Basic Authentication?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

How can I use the Webrequest `Credentials` Property to send an basic authentication header?
Why isn't the Authorization header send with the request even when`PreAuthenticate` is set to true?

```
WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.github.com/user");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("githubUsername", "githubPassword");
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server should send a HTTP 401 Not Authorized response code *containing* a WWW-Authenticate HTTP header.

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="example"
```

The PreAuthenticate property only works *after* authentication has taken place. From MSDN:

> true to send an HTTP Authorization header with requests after
>   authentication has taken place; otherwise, false. The default is
>   false.

See other answers for more in depth explanation.

Comment: Thanks for that Jos.  I am a lot more informed now.

Answer (score 4):

I've done some additional research based on [Måns Tånneryd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836258/mans-tanneryd)`s answer. And the link he posted in his comment: [PreAuthenticate Property of WebRequest - Problem](http://www.cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/000580.html).

First of all as described in his link the [HttpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.preauthenticate.aspx) does NOT send the Authentication header PRE authentication, but pre sends it in following requests, after Authentication. From MSDN:

> true to send an HTTP Authorization header with requests after authentication has taken place; otherwise, false. The default is false.

So even with the `PreAuthenticate` property set to true, we still need an WWW-Authenticate challenge with a 401 Unauthorized before anything happens. Now if we try to authenticate against github with the following code:

```
WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.github.com/user");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("githubUsername", "githubPassword");

var response = request.GetResponse();
```

An `WebException` will be thrown, because we don't get a WWW-Authenticate challenge. If we capture this in Fiddler we will get the following:

[image]

However if we try this, with the exact same code, against a website that does return a WWW-Authenticate challenge we will see the following in Fiddler:

[image]
[image]

And the response will have the result as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I can successfull run this code accessing another server that also requires both SSL and authentication. This server differs from the github in that the github returns a json result saying that it requires authentication and the other server returns a "classic" 401 html page. Sniffing the network you can see that the .net code tries to do anonymous auth even if you do set preauth to true which I think is rather confusing. However, upon receiving a regular 401-page it tries again, and this time with the auth info and everything works. It seems to me though as if .net reacts differently upon receiving the json version of a 401, not making a second try.

I guess this is not the answer you are looking for but hopefully it sheds some more light on the situation.

Comment: I found both an explanation and a solution at Charles Cooks blog. Explanation is at http://www.cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/000580.html and a solution can be found at http://www.cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/000581.html.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it sheds a nice light on the situation. Also the links you provided are helpful. Tonight I'll take some more time and try if I can successful authenticate against another server. Is the server you tried a public server which I could try to authenticate as well? I still wonder if their is a way to handle the JSON 401 with the Credential Property / to Authenticate Github with it. So I'll leave the question open for now.

Comment: The server I was using is, unfortunately, not public.

Comment: Thanks Måns! I got it working and shared some off my findings in another answer and I have marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: Happy to be of assistance. I have stumbled upon this situation before but never taken the time to figure out how come the preauth property wasn't resulting in the behavior I expected and simply accepted that the request round trips twice instead of once.